# Mysql Insert on duplicated key with last_insert_id not working

Tags: mysql

```
create table test1 ( 
   id int not null auto_increment primary key, 
   a varchar(16), b varchar(16) 
);


INSERT INTO test1 (a,b) VALUES ('a1','b3') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), b='3';
```

The above line should insert an entry since the table is empty.

```
INSERT INTO test1 (a,b) VALUES ('a1','b3') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), b='3';
```

Run the line again, it should replace `b` with `"3"` since `a1, b3` already exist. But mysql adds another line for me. I have searched awhile and can not find a solution.

Latest update: Thanks for all your help. I figured one of the column must be unique.

Alter table test1 add unique (a)

solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `ON DUPLICATE` is only triggered if the column has a `UNIQUE KEY`. Try adding a UNIQUE INDEX on your table on the `a` or `b` columns and it should work as intended.

Comment: the id is a primary key. will that be considered as unique index? Thanks

Comment: A primary key is a special case of a UNIQUE INDEX, so yes. But since your INSERT does not create a duplicate value of the primary key, the update clause is not used.

Answer (score 1):

There is no duplicate key in your case. Only unique column in your table is `primary key id`

Try

```
INSERT INTO test1 (id,a,b) VALUES (1,'a1','b3') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), b='3';
```

twice.
First line of documentation says.

```
If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old row is performed.
```

See the full [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: If test1 (id,a,b) is used, will only the id=1 being updated? I tried to setup column "a" to not null, Insert result is the same.
Also, since id is auto increment, it must be set to primary key. I can not use column a as primary.
thanks.

Comment: I didn't get what are you saying. The main point is this can be used only on primary key or unique index.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. "id" is the primary key in my case. However, 
INSERT INTO test1 (id,a,b) VALUES (1,'a1','b3') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), b='3';
that will only change the entry when id=1. If I do not know the id, I won't be able to update data.
Thanks.

Comment: In that case make some column(s) as unique index ...in this case it may be on 'a', alter table test1 unique index (a);